# In IEEE citation style how do I cite different sections of a book

Tags: publications, citation-style, ieee

This is not a specific LaTeX question, hence why I post it here.

I am typing a report for a project. I use multiple sections of a handbook (say, page 113-116, a bit later 389-390, etc.). What is the proper way to deal with this? Should I include a separate citation for each? I've looked at the [IEEE editorial standard](https://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf) but they don't mention this.

LaTeX thing: If yes, is there a way to do it with bibtex without copy-pasting the entire thing in my .bib file and just changing page number?

Answer (score 4):

In LaTeX you can simply write:

```
 Bla bla bla \cite[p.~3]{ReferenceKey}.
```

which produces

> Bla bla bla [1, p. 3].

where [1] corresponds to key `ReferenceKey`.

For more information, you might find this video enlightening (2:28)
 http://libraryguides.vu.edu.au/ieeereferencing/gettingstarted

Comment: I edited to restructure so the answer appears at the top. I hope that's okay. I'm not sure what "(2:28)" means nor why you include *As a result...*, perhaps the latter is supposed to be an example? I've assumed so and included as a block quote, by all means revise if that wasn't intended.

Comment: @user2768 (2:28) is the time of the video at which there is the relevant piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

In the [IEEE editorial standard](https://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf) you linked to, you will find the answer on page one in the books section. Example [2] says:

> [2]  L. Stein,  “Random  patterns,” in  *Computers and You*,  J. S.  Brake, Ed. New  York:  Wiley,  1994, pp. 55-70.

*Computers and You* is the book title. "Random patterns" is the cited section/chapter.

If you wanted to cite another section/chapter of the same book (let's say with title "X", author A. Nobody and on pages 100-110) you would have to add a second reference in the bibliography:

> [3]  A. Nobody,  “X,” in  *Computers and You*,  J. S.  Brake, Ed. New  York:  Wiley,  1994, pp. 100-110.

Comment: I knew how to do a book reference/citation. The question I had was how to deal with it being referenced multiple times. I wasn't sure it I just had to add the reference again with a different page number. I could image it was not the case, since in my case you would have 5 identical references with exception of the page numbers

Comment: The example I showed is for a book called *Computers and You* where each section/chapter has another author and the book itself has an editor called *S. Brake*. Are you talking about a book without editor(s) and only overall author(s)? If so, you have two options: 1) Add the book as one reference in the bibliography giving only the overall page numbers. Then you have to be precise in the in-text-citation. 2) Add each section you want to cite seperately **as shown above** (giving the section in quotation marks and the book in italic). Then you have the exact page ranges for each section.